# Want to show icons/options when user hovers over a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the problem I'm looking to solve:

- I have many elements on the page, such as links within a text block, for which I want the user to have easy access to contextual actions
- I don't want to rely on a right-click contextual menu because it's opaque - a user wouldn't know that they could right-click unless they were taught to do so
- A hover menu would be better because users are likely to mouse over these elements for other purposes

Here's the functionality I'm looking to create which I think would solve the problem:

- Ability to mark elements on a page such that, when a user hovers over them, the element will be wrapped in a container with some icons or links next to it
- The element must remain in the exact same position on the screen (i.e. no shifting of text)
- The targeted elements can be inline as well as block

Of course, I know it's extremely easy to show some icons or something when you hover over an element.  The problem is, the icons would disappear when you mouseout.  The solution to that problem would be to wrap the element in some visual container and as long as the user is within that container, the icons would remain.  I'm hoping that someone has already written a jQuery plugin or something similar which fits the requirements.  Of course, I'm open to other completely different solutions.

Here's a visual example of what I'm looking to do.  You have some link on the page and when you hover over it, it gets "wrapped" in a button with some icons off to the side.
[image]

Comment: post you html and css code

Comment: I would do this very simply. Put a container around the button and the menu. Have the menu hidden by default. On `mouseover` of the container (including button / menu), add a class to the container that will show the menu. On `mouseout`, add a *timer* to remove the class that is canceled if you hover back in. This creates some error forgiveness in mouse movement. Some hover-over menus can be very unforgiving and I agree with what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TamilSelvan: What HTML and CSS?  I'm not asking to help fix a bug in my code.  I'm asking for help designing a solution to a generic problem.

Comment: @Jaw.shYeah I hear what you're saying and that was my initial thought as well but one hard requirement is that there is no visual shifting of the element.  It should appear as though a box appeared around it, in place.  Whatever the solution is, it would probably involve cloning the element and using absolute positioning as anything within the current flow of the page would make elements shift.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a question. However, you could wrap the anchor in a div and use a negative margin to keep the text from shifting.

**HTML**

```
Here is some text and <div class="fancy"><a href="#" >some link</a></div>.
```

**CSS**

```
.fancy {
    line-height:160%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.fancy:hover {
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius:4px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin:0 -10px;
}
```

Then using a little jQuery you could just append on mouseover and remove on mouseout.

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$( ".fancy" ).mouseover(function() {
  $( this ).append( "<span class=\"something\"> &reg;&copy;</span>" );
}).mouseout(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".something" ).remove();
});
```

There are probably a ton of different ways to accomplish what you need, but this seems like it could be one solution.

[See example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0xzq8wm/1/).

Comment: Thanks.  This is a good attempt at an answer.  I'm having some problems with it in that the newly appended icons trigger a mouseout, such that the user can't select them.  But it's a much narrower problem that I can work on.

Comment: Using `.mouseleave()` and adding a delay should help with that issue. 
http://jsfiddle.net/u0xzq8wm/2/